# Selenium stops to work after call FindElements

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

Sometimes when I call the Selenium FindElements(By), it throws an exception and my driver stops to work. The parameter "BY" maybe can be the problem: when I use a different by to search the same elements, it works.

Also I could see that even if my element exists or if it this same method with the same argument was called before, it does not prevents the method to throws an exception.

My method is:

```
    public IWebElement SafeFindElement(By by)
    {
        try
        {
            IWebElement element;
            if (_driver.FindElements(by).Any())
            {
                element = _driver.FindElements(by).First();
                return element;
            }

            return null;
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException)
        {
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

An exemple of BY value that do not works all the time (even if it exists in the page):

```
By.CssSelector("input[data-id-selenium='entrar']")
```

The exception:

> WebDriverException
>
> The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL
>   http://localhost:46432/session/ef6cd2f1bf3ed5c924fe29d0f2c677cf/elements
>   timed out after 60 seconds.

I have no idea what it can be or what cause this instability. There is someone with any sugestion?

**@EDIT**

I found a temporary solution.

Early, I was trying to find the element using:

```
var element = browser
    .FindElements(By.CssSelector("input[data-id-selenium='entrar']")
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Or

```
var element = browser
    .FindElements(By.XPath("//input[@data-id-selenium='entrar']");
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Now, I'm using:

```
var element = browser
    .FindElements(By.TagName("input"))
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetAttribute("data-id-selenium") == "entrar");
```

They do the same thing, but the firsts throws an exception without a reason. Also, it is a temporary solution and I'm trying solve the problem to search the element only using Selectors.

Comment: That error isn't caused by how you're searching for the element. When you can't find the element, you get `ElementNotFoundException`

Comment: I think it only occurs using FindElement. When i try using FindElements (more than one occurrence), if selenium can't find any result it returns a empty list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I'm using a method in all my test suit to wait the loading message dismiss. But it try using jquery and not all pages in my application use it.

So, selenium give up try execute jquery after 60 seconds and returns a timeout error, but this error does not broken the Selenium driver, only the FindElements then it returns a empty list. And when it try to return the empty list, all the drive broke.

The original method:

```
public void WaitLoadingMessage(int timeout)
{
    while (timeout > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            var loadingIsVisible = _js.ExecuteScript("return $('#loading-geral').is(':visible');").ToString();

            if (loadingIsVisible.ToLower() == "false")
                break;

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            timeout -= 1000;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (!ex.Message.ToLower().Contains("$ is not defined"))
                throw;
        }
    }
}
```

And the correction:

```
public void WaitLoadingMessage(int timeout)
{
    while (timeout > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            var loadingIsVisible = _js.ExecuteScript("return $('#loading-geral').is(':visible');").ToString();

            if (loadingIsVisible.ToLower() == "false")
                break;

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            timeout -= 1000;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (!ex.Message.ToLower().Contains("$ is not defined"))
                throw;

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue for selenium, the webdriver server has a maximum timeout limit of 60 seconds for each request and there isn't a way that i'm aware of to change that, i suggest that you consider using explicit wait before using FindElement(), although this issue might occur, there's a workaround for this issue that has worked for me, using extension methods that i have implemented, the idea is to wait for specific condition so that if the webdriver threw an exception that says it has waited for the maximum limit of 60 secs, you could handle that by trying to wait for a specific condition repeatedly for a specific period of time, each time you loop a new request is sent to the webdriver server.

```
    public static void WaitUntil(this IWebDriver webDriver, Func<IWebDriver, bool> predicate, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        var dtStart = DateTime.Now;

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!predicate(webDriver))
                    throw new Exception();

                break;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(dtStart) >= timeout)
                    throw ex;
            }

            Thread.Sleep(30000);
        }
    }
    public static void WaitUntil(this IWebDriver webDriver, Func<IWebDriver, IWebElement> predicate, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        var dtStart = DateTime.Now;

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                predicate(webDriver);
                break;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(dtStart) >= timeout)
                    throw ex;
            }

            Thread.Sleep(30000);
        }
    }
```

you could for example use the extension methods like that

```
webDriver.WaitUntil(w => w.Title == "title", TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
```

or

```
webDriver.WaitUntil(ExpectedConditions.TitleIs("title"), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
```

or

```
webDriver.WaitUntil(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("elementId")), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
```

**Update**

After reviewing your last comment, you said that you got some elements when you have used FindElements(By.TagName("input"); that mean that the selector you are using is causing the problem, you could find elements by tag name then filter the results by the attribute value, or if you are certain that the selector you are using is correct and is not behaving correctly, try to debug the issue, also if there's any javascript that is responsible for setting the attribute value, make sure that it runs first using implicit or explicit wait before calling FindElement().

Comment: Hi, Khaled Kholy! Thanks for your answer, but it did not work. The same exception throws when the method try execute the "predicate(webDriver)", and my webDriver stops to work again. There is not a error to check if the element really exist in the page (I can assert it exists checking in the browser console using selectors), but is something like when the driver try to find it, and even the browser displaying the elements in the page and it be possible select they in console (as example $("input[data-id-selenium='entrar']")), the driver throws the same exception.

Comment: Did you try anything else rather than this example $("input[data-id-selenium='entrar']") ?, i mean finding an element by id, or by tag name, and how did you implement $("input[data-id-selenium='entrar']") using selenium?

Comment: Sometimes when I change the selector, works. In this case, even using class, id or whatever, it fails. I start my request using my own method  `browser.HasElement(By.CssSelector("input[data-id-selenium='entrar']"))`   , and inside the method "HasElement", I call the SafeFindElement as     `bool hasElement = SafeFindElement(@by) != null`   You can see my method "SafeFindElement" in the post.

Comment: "Sometimes when I change the selector, works"
Do you encounter the same issue using browser.HasElement(By.TagName("input")); ?

Comment: Using `browser.HasElement(By.TagName("input"));`, Selenium finds some elements, but using the previous selector does not work. Also, I tried to using a Xpath selector like `browser.HasElement(By.XPath("//input[@data-id-selenium='entrar']"))`, but it does not works too. I think is possible solve the problem "temporarily", finding the elements using `By.TagName("input")` and filtering they using linq to check if my desired input exists or no. Whatever, I want to solve the problem in the correct way.

Comment: I only don't understand why Selenium throws exceptions when my parameter is a valid selector. If I always filter my result using linq, I can't do a generic method to check the elements, so all my consults will need a linq filter than a valid and reusable css selector? Because it will grant me use only BY statement. If I execute in console `$("input[data-id-selenium='entrar']")` it will returns the expected result, but it not occurs in Selenium. The element always exists in page, if not was only necessary wait the attribute value change to desired