# Different XPATH in different browsers

Tags: selenium, xpath, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a testsuite, which uses `WebDriver 3.5.2` ad `ChromeDriver 2.31`.
I checked xpath for element in `Google Chrome` and I defined it in testcase. I set `ChromeDriver` in headless mode.

When I execute test I get follwoing error:

> org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed:
>   waiting for presence of element located by: By.xpath:
>   //*[@id="formA"]/p[1]/label (tried for 30 second(s) with 500
>   MILLISECONDS interval)

This xpath exists on webpage if I check it manually from browser. Webpage loads in a few seconds, so 30 should be enough.

Comment: Can you share the URL of mentioned webpage?

Comment: @Andersson : Sorry, it is only reachable from internal network.

Comment: Check if there is any frame present

Comment: @ShubhamJain : I can't see any frames and it is working, when I execute it in a Portable Firefox and as I know xpath should be the same.

Comment: cool .. so you problem is resolved?

Comment: Does the same code works with Firefox (geckodriver) or any other webdriver?

Comment: Problem is not yet resolved, situation is the same. Yes, it is ok in Firefox.

Comment: Try to [take screenshot of page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422262/take-a-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver) or [get outerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263824/get-html-source-of-webelement-in-selenium-webdriver-using-python) of any `div` which is ancestor of target `label` to check whether it's actually present

Comment: @Andersson : I get only a white png file as a screenshot.

Comment: perhaps your website is not compatible with Chrome in headless mode?  I have no idea how to test that.

Comment: Maybe you problem is the same that this one: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31437515/selenium-stops-to-work-after-call-findelements). Also, check if the element exists inside the outerHTML as Andersson told you.

Comment: I checked it already, it is working perfectly, when I use browser in normal mode and not in headless.

Comment: @plaidshirt try to get the outerHTML code debugging your test and try to find the desired node in a xml finding website, this way you can see if it was modifcated. If it is, just update your xpath or create a generic for both cases. If not... well, maybe try to change your xpath of a simplest and try again

Comment: @StriterAlfa : I don't know why should I check outerHTML. Test is working correctly in normal mode. So xpath should be ok. It is not working only in headless. Why should I change my code to make it working in headless browser too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `FluentWait`. Pass the `By test =By.xpath("//*[@id="formA"]/p[1]/label")` to below function

```
WebElement waitsss(WebDriver driver, By elementIdentifier){
Wait<WebDriver> wait =
new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver).withTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS) .pollingEvery(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

return wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>()
{
public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
return driver.findElement(elementIdentifier);
}});
}
```

Code for Explicit wait:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("YOUR LOCTOR")));
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: 30 seconds is enough for this webpage to be loaded.

Comment: try first with 60. if it is working then we will set the threshold.

Comment: Same with this too.

Comment: I have added code for Explicit wait as well.. try with it

Comment: is your xpath is different on the page which pop-up after script run

Comment: I can't see it, because I use now ChromeDriver in headless mode.

Comment: comment out the headless argument and check.. if it work on normal way then it should work in headless

Comment: It is not the same in headless and normal. It can find the given element in normal, but not in headless.